# Dúvida angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gostaria de saber por que no angular js tem esse tipo de declaração: (exemplo)

```
ab.setType                     = setType;
ab.getType                     = getType;
ab.getTitle                    = getTitle;
ab.calculateTimeOfWork         = calculateTime; 
ab.showCompleteListOfPromoters = showCompleteList;
```

Comment: -----------------------------------

Comment: ------------------------------------

Comment: ---------------------------------------